# Implementing Swipe and Click in Android Button

Tags: android, onclicklistener, swipe-gesture

I am new to android development, I tried to implement swipe (using Ontouch) for Activity and click events for the buttons in activity. If I swipe on top of buttons, swipe event is not getting generated.

If i add swipe for buttons, onclick event for the buttons are not getting generated.

What am i supposed to do, to solve this problem.

In case of any clarification, please ask me.

Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/default_2x"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LearnUpperCaseActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/learn_uppercase"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="11"
            android:background="@drawable/main_area_blue_2x" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/question"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/instruction"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tab_below" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/button_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:padding="3dp" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
                    android:onClick="button1Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/brown_button_2x"
                    android:onClick="button2Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/dark_green_2x"
                    android:onClick="button3Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/row1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/fluora_button_2x"
                    android:onClick="button4Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/green_button_2x"
                    android:onClick="button5Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/maroon_2x"
                    android:onClick="button6Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/row2"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/yellow_button_2x"
                    android:onClick="button7Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/purple_button_2x"
                    android:onClick="button8Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/pink_button_2x"
                    android:onClick="button9Pressed"
                    android:text="@string/hard_coded_char" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/row3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/home"
                    style="@style/UpperCaseButton"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_margin="3dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/blue_long_button_2x"
                    android:onClick="home"
                    android:text="@string/home" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

see the image in this link. https://sites.google.com/site/temptemptemp123tempqwe/doubt.jpg?attredirects=0

Please help me to solve this issue.

Regards,
Bennet.

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: Please find the complete code in the link. Thank you so much for asking details, please suggest me some solutions for this problem. https://sites.google.com/site/temptemptemp123tempqwe/Sample.rar

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to process the difference between the coordinates while pressing and releasing the button.

Add this to the `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final float len = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi/6;
            OnTouch Listener controlButtonTouchListener=new View.OnTouchListener() {
                float initX;
                float initY;
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch(event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            initX = event.getX();
                            initY = event.getY();
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            initX -= event.getX(); //now has difference value
                            initY -= event.getY(); //now has difference value
                            if (initY > len) {
                                ((Button)v).setText("Swipe up");
                                //Toast.makeText(context,"Swipe up",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if(initY < -len) {
                                ((Button)v).setText("Swipe Down");
                                //Toast.makeText(context,"Swipe Down",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                if(initY < 0) initY = -initY;
                                if(initX < 0) initX = -initX;
                                if(initX <= len/4 && initY <= len/4) {
                                    ((Button)v).setText("Clicked");
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            };
            findViewById(R.id.ClickSwipeButton).setOnTouchListener(controlButtonTouchListener);
        }
```

Comment: Ever heard about GestureDetector? https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

Comment: Gesture detection is more complicated. You need to detect finger move after touch with `case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :' and trace the path to find meaning of finger move . That's how it's done, but I have never tried

Comment: Your code does detect a gesture (albeit crudely), a fling to be specific. `GestureDetector` listener provides a `onFling` method specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry on that case all I know is to detect swipes and clicks. Can't do anything about gegstures.

Comment: I'm trying to explain that a click is a gesture. A swipe is a gesture (also called fling). Long click, double tap are all gestures. Read the article, maybe you won't have to reinvent the wheel next time.

Comment: I was using a GestureDetector but it wasn't possible to get Click event along with swipeUp and SwipeDown Flings. I had to set a clicklistener separately but this solution combines both in the same. Kudos!

Comment: Use `v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);` inside onTouch before switch case if your view has a scroll on it otherwise won't detect swipes.