# Android: Detecting Swipe As Well as Click on a Button

Tags: android, android-studio, swipe

I have created an emergency pager as my first Android app. Some users are reporting that they can't turn off the pager sound and they have to stop the app completely. I think this may because in the heat of the moment they are sliding their finger across the Silence Button and therefore creating a swipe instead of a touch.

The button on my Activity XML file is

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_gotit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:onClick="gotit"
    android:text="@string/silence"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
```

and the relevant part of the corresponding Java file is

```
    public void gotit(View view) {
    vibrator.cancel();
    ringtone.stop();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SummaryActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, inc_summary);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How can I add in "swipe" (and possibly "fling", which I'd never heard of until today) so that the button responds whatever the user does to it?

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38080889/15298643) ? No luck?

Comment: javdromero, I looked at your suggestion, thanks. Now I've had some more user reports though and it seems that it's not swipes that are causing the problem. So I'm having to tackle it from a different direction.